# Choppy scrolling with ScrollView when updating View while scrolling SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am using my own `ScrollView` which has scroll start and end callbacks, so that I can perform some actions based on them, like hiding/showing a banner.

Here's my code for `ScrollView`

```
struct TrackableScrollView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    private let onScrollingStarted: () -> Void
    private let onScrollingFinished: () -> Void
    @State var scrollViewHelper = ScrollViewHelper()
    let content: Content

    public init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content,
                onScrollingStarted: @escaping () -> Void = {},
                onScrollingFinished: @escaping () -> Void = {}) {
        self.content = content()
        self.onScrollingStarted = onScrollingStarted
        self.onScrollingFinished = onScrollingFinished
    }

    public var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { outsideProxy in
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    GeometryReader { insideProxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .preference(key: ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self, value: [self.calculateContentOffset(fromOutsideProxy: outsideProxy, insideProxy: insideProxy)])
                    }
                    self.content
                }
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self) { value in
                scrollViewHelper.currentOffset = value[0]
            }
            .simultaneousGesture(
                DragGesture().onChanged { _ in
                    onScrollingStarted()
                }
            )
            .onReceive(scrollViewHelper.$offsetAtScrollEnd) { _ in
                onScrollingFinished()
            }
        }
    }

    private func calculateContentOffset(fromOutsideProxy outsideProxy: GeometryProxy, insideProxy: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        return outsideProxy.frame(in: .global).minY - insideProxy.frame(in: .global).minY
    }
}

private struct ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = [CGFloat]
    static var defaultValue: [CGFloat] = [0]

    static func reduce(value: inout [CGFloat], nextValue: () -> [CGFloat]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}

class ScrollViewHelper: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @Published var offsetAtScrollEnd: CGFloat = 0

    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

    init() {
        cancellable = AnyCancellable($currentOffset
            .debounce(for: 0.3, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .dropFirst()
            .assign(to: \.offsetAtScrollEnd, on: self))
    }
}
```

And here's my code to show some content

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var messageBannerVisisbility: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TrackableScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) { i in
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                            .overlay(Text("\(i)"))
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
            } onScrollingStarted: {
                hideMessageBanner()
            } onScrollingFinished: {
                showMessageBanner()
            }

            if messageBannerVisisbility {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 100)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .overlay(Text("Random bottom view"))
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom).combined(with: .opacity))
            }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .onAppear {
            showMessageBanner()
        }
    }
}
```

I am toggling `messageBannerVisisbility` with animation inside `showMessageBanner()` function.

If I keep below code, scrolling is not smooth. Could it be because I am showing/hiding the banner with animation on scroll callbacks? I guess I can just update the banner, instead of the whole View, but I am not sure how can I achieve that!

```
if messageBannerVisisbility {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 100)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .overlay(Text("Random bottom view"))
                        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom).combined(with: .opacity))
                }
```

What could I do to improve scrolling experience? My app does support iOS 13, but I am also fine with implementing 2 different solutions, one for iOS 13 and other one for iOS 14 and above, if that makes life a little easier!

Comment: When you run your simulator and scroll, and you check if your CPU usage is high? If it is, I would wonder if calculations are being made too rapidly and stressing the iPhone and thus the performance of your scroll.

Comment: @KhoiNguyen The CPU usage is not high when I scroll, however, scrolling is choppy if I keep the code to hide/show bottom rectangle view with animation.